# unable to login to CISCO management IP

Tags: cisco, storage, switch

I 'm inable to login to my fabric CISCO switch ( MDS 9506) through management IP
It's giving an error- when logging it from Device manager

"10.20.XX.XX" timed out

Busy Network, No Route, or snmpd is unresponsive.

Fabric manager has also become unmanagable

> SNMP engine ID discovery timed out
>
> --Busy Network
>
> --No route from null/0.0.0.0
>
> -- 10.20.XX.XX is unresponsive

Plus, i 'm unable to ping the management ip ( 10.20.XX.XX) ; unable to telnet.

Has any one encountered this b'fore?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all go in through a serial link (9600-N-1), as admin - from there check the management IP, netmask, gateway and check you can ping that gateway too. Also restart snmpd. If this doesn't work you have either an odd SAN-OS/NS-OS config, a kind-of-broken Supervisor or local network segment. Feel free to reboot the Supervisors (one at a time of course).

   2. If you can boot the fabric-manager machine from a live linux CD, if you can do this check that you can ping your own gateway, if you can that you can then ping the gateway of the MDS and again if that works go for the MDS management port. If you can't ping all this way you have a local LAN problem or hardware problem.
   3. If the live linux CD booted FM machine can ping the MDS and the MDS can ping the FM machine then the next step is to boot your FM machine as normal and try logging in via both FM and DM - let us know how you get on if this doesn't work.

Has anything changed on the MDS? do you use autosave or log commands via syslog - if so it might be worth checking if anything's changed recently - though I suspect this is either a Supervisor-gone-wonky (and needing a reboot) or a local network issue.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation , Chopper3 ( i know,  you 're the CISCO king :) ). I will work on it the coming Monday , and let you know how it goes.  Between, nice to be back here and have you guide me. Thanks again for your time .

Comment: Hi chopper , I know it's month old pending work. But, it needs to be checked now. I have this now-There is a green Ethernet wire plugged into the management port on both switches; I will need to unplug this in order to plug a laptop in. What ip / subnet should I assign to the laptop to allow communication with the switch through this Ethernet port? Also will this cause any outage or issues with this switch?

Comment: You should have a serial port somewhere on your supervisor.